# Finding lengh of dotted line

Tags: geometry

A friend is trying to work out this algebra problem.

If the big square is =1, what is the length of the dotted line?

[image]

How do you even go about solving this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question is not about [algebraic geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_geometry).

Comment: What have you tried? (The answer is 1.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The black outlined, inscribed square has a side length of $1/\sqrt{2}$ and a diagonal of $1$. You then might aim to calculate the position of the pink dot by means of Pythagoras according to

$$(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+a)^2+a^2=1$$

But you do not even have to!

The lower bond of that dotted line is a shifted copy of the opposite copy wrt. that small pink square. The other bond in the very same way wrt. the upper pink square. Therefore the searched for dotted distance is exactly the same as the diagonal of the black outlined square. And that one already is mentioned to be $1$.

--- rk

Comment: What he means is that the dotted line connecting the upper right corners of the two pink squares would be the same distance as the line connecting the bottom left corners of the two pink squares. This second copy is the diagonal of the black square, which is 1.